# Recursion error with Python 3 copy.deepcopy

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, biopython

I am currently using the BioPython `Bio.PDB` module to parse and read protein structure files (PDB files). I have run into recursion issues when trying to create a deep copy of the `structure` object returned by the `PDBParser().get_structure(...)` method.

I was under the impression that the `copy.deepcopy` function was designed to deal with recursion? Strangely, this is only an issue using Python 3. Running equivalent code in Python 2.7 works fine (uses `urllib2` instead of `urllib`).

Is this a bug in `copy.deepcopy`? Or an issue with `Biopython`?

A minimal example (*Python 3.6, Biopython 1.68*) is:

```
import urllib.request
from io import StringIO
from copy import deepcopy
import Bio.PDB

pdb_name = '1zro'
#Download file
pdb_url = "http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/files/" + pdb_name + ".pdb"
pdb_file = urllib.request.urlopen(pdb_url)
#Create string stream for Bio.PDB to read:
pdb_input_stream = StringIO(pdb_file.read().decode('utf-8'))

#Make Bio.PDB structure object
parser = Bio.PDB.PDBParser()
structure = parser.get_structure(pdb_name, pdb_input_stream)

#Attempt to perform a deepcopy on Bio.PDB Structure:
structure_copy = deepcopy(structure)
```

Full traceback:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 215, in _deepcopy_list
    append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 215, in _deepcopy_list
    append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 215, in _deepcopy_list
    append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 215, in _deepcopy_list
    append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 281, in _reconstruct
    if hasattr(y, '__setstate__'):
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Bio/PDB/Entity.py", line 207, in __getattr__
    if not hasattr(self, 'selected_child'):
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Bio/PDB/Entity.py", line 207, in __getattr__
    if not hasattr(self, 'selected_child'):
  File "/home/andrew/Programs/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Bio/PDB/Entity.py", line 207, in __getattr__
    if not hasattr(self, 'selected_child'):
  [Previous line repeated 318 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: You might be interesting about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it

Comment: Thanks @sangheestyle, I have already tried increased the recursion limit to stupid levels, and have achieved nothing more than a segfault. But that was my first thought as well.

Comment: I see. Hmm.. What else...

Comment: Just googled _"python3.6 deepcopy issues"_ and looking at some of the posts, namely [this](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/issues/648) one. It could quite possibly be an issue with deepcopy for 3.6, see if python3.5 gives same issue since I've seen a couple problems arise due to 3.6

Comment: Have a look at [this recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/302535/). I haven't tested it, but it might help. And, according the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html), this is always something to watch out for when using deepcopy: "Recursive objects (compound objects that, directly or indirectly, contain a reference to themselves) may cause a recursive loop."

Comment: @StevenSummers, I've tried with 3.4 and the same issue.

Comment: @DanWelty, yep, that's one option for an immediate fix. More interested in solving the issue for deepcopy though, as that seems to be the go-to tool when performance isn't an issue.

Comment: @AndrewGuy Do the test cases in the post mentioned by DanWelty also have the same result for Python 2.7?

Comment: @StevenSummers The test cases in DanWelty's post have the same result in both 2.7 and 3.6, unlike my scenario.

Comment: @AndrewGuy Maybe submit an issue on the github page to check. But I can still only think that deepcopy for python 3 is the issue. Maybe check the max recursion depth of the structure to see how deep it goes before exiting on both versions. Also try `>>> deepcopy(nested(496))` should work, but any higher and it hits the limit in 3.5 on my device (Windows 10).

Comment: @StevenSummers Thanks for the link to that troposphere issue. The fix suggested there solves the issue for BioPython as well - cheers for the pointer in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Andrew kindly filed this as Biopython issue https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/787 - although we're still not sure what is going wrong under Python 3 here.

Comment: Thanks for flagging that Peter. I'm more and more convinced that it's a `deepcopy` issue it its root, but haven't yet figured out what exactly is going on. Going to try and put together a minimal example that replicates the issues when I have time.